# android mobile - send a SMS with ftp link

Tags: android, mobile, ftp

I'm trying to send a SMS from mobile to another mobile.
The SMS contains a ftp link. 
For example, I want to send the following link: ftp://ftp.example.com. 
When the user will open the SMS, the link will be like that ftp://[ftp.example.com](http://ftp.example.com) in the message body.
When the user click this link, the chrome browser will show with the link : http://ftp.example.com

Thank's, Idan

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android **Built-in SMS app** to send the message, then your code be like this-

```
String smsBody = "ftp://ftp.example.com";
String phNumber = "123456";

Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address",phNumber); //optional, in case you want a default phone number 
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",smsBody);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

If you are using the **SmsManager** to send message, then the code be like this-

```
String smsBody = "ftp://ftp.example.com";
String phNumber = "123456";

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phNumber, null, smsBody, null, null);
```

And don't forget to give the **SEND_SMS** permission for both.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. My problem isn't relative to code. The link sent with another way. I want to send the link from one mobile to another with the standart SMS (The android os).